# 80s animation, three witch sisters sharing an eye, blue-faced bad guy with a large moustache

Tags: story-identification

Had to be '84 or '85 when I watched it on VHS, but I specifically remember an ANIMATED fantasy movie where there was a protagonist who was dealing with three witch sisters who shared one eye (as in, popping it into a socket, then a sister would get it out of the socket and place it in her own to use it). And then later in the same movie, a somewhat blue-faced bad guy with a large mustache has his nose and mustache swiped back and forth by the protagonist's baton.

I know how utterly vague this is, I'm just hoping someone else remembers the imagery described and what movie it was.

Comment: Can you remember the general art style? More western or eastern (anime)?

Comment: Not anime or eastern, very similar to western fantasy typical of bakshi, or bass/rankin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be [*Metamorphoses*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamorphoses_(film)) from 1979, also titled *Winds of Change*? It was a Japanese movie based on Greek myths, but animated in a more Western-looking style, and one of the myths adapted was Perseus, who did steal the shared eyeball of the [Graeae Sisters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeae) in the original myth. The full movie is on youtube below, at 1:04:39 Perseus is told "to find Medusa you must seek the three witches with one eye between them", then he comes across the witches starting at 1:05:47.

Don't know if there's a scene with a bad guy's nose being tweaked by a baton though, I haven't watched it all the way through.

Comment: dude, that's incredible. That's the scene to a "T". You guys are amazing

Answer (score 3):

This sounds a lot like *Disney's Hercules*, although it's from 1997.

You've got three "witches" (the *Fates*) who share one common eye and you've got *Hades* as the main villain who's blue. No mustache, but IIRC his flaming hair moves around quite a bit during some scenes.

Comment: Well, That scene is definitely along the vibe of what I'm describing, but the movie predates it by at 10-12 years, and wasn't anything Disney. What ever I saw is obscure and was on vhs back around the time of Flight of the Dragons, etc...

Comment: Okay, so it's definitely been earlier then.

Answer (score 0):

The greek Greae Sisters (or Gray Sisters) have appeared in numerous live action films and animations. The Disney's Hercules could be a possibility but this animation movie is from 1997.

A second possibility would be the Clash of the Titans from 1981 but this is not an animation movie.

Comment: Yes, the first thing that I thought was Clash of the Titans until I saw that it was animated.

Answer (score 0):

[The Black Cauldron](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihuOfUM4f8U) (1985) contains a scene with the three weird sisters, but otherwise it isn't a very close match (they don't share an eye in the movie).